# CentOS 6.4 and alternate SSH port not working

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat, iptables, centos6

I've got a CentOS 6.4 machine and would like to change the default SSH port, and followed these instructions:

[CentOS Wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH#head-3579222198adaf43a3ecbdc438ebce74da40d8ec)

After making those changes (including the "semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 2345"), and restarting SSHD, I'm still not able to connect via the new, alternate port.

I see that the host is listening on the new port:

```
# netstat -antp | grep 2345 | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2345                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      6998/sshd           
tcp        0      0 :::2345                     :::*                        LISTEN      6998/sshd
```

And I see the SELINUX policy appears to be correct:

```
# /usr/sbin/semanage port -l | grep ssh
ssh_port_t                     tcp      2345, 22
```

And I see the IPTABLES appear to be correct, too:

```
# iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:domain 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:bootps 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:bootps 
 179K  145M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
  185  7200 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    2    99 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
   39  2028 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
29763   11M REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    virbr0  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24    state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 any     192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    virbr0  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 118K packets, 24M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Lastly, I can telnet to the port locally:

```
# telnet localhost 2345
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
```

But cannot telnet to or SSH to the new, alternate port from outside.

I'm not behind a firewall of any sort.

Any ideas, suggestions? I'm flummoxed.

Dan

Comment: Dan - you seem to have asked a number of questions on SO recently that are not programming-related - you should probably be posting these on http://superuser.com rather than http://stackoverflow.com as they are off-topic here. Thanks.

Comment: Will do. I've had such great results here, but I'll still ask it on superuser.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't know what the semanage command is doing in detail.)

But it seems to me that the problem is the firewall. I don't see the port 2345 being accepted. 
What I see is:

```
39  2028 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
```

but here ssh is meaning port 22, as defined by /etc/services (unless centos/semanage are doing strange things).

Answer (score 0):

The missing ingredient for me (CentOS8) was the following commands:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=2345/tcp --permanent

firewall-cmd --reload
```

I did all the other stuff (including `selinux` even though it is disabled for me) but could not use the new port remotely until I did the above `firewall-cmd`.
Of course your `"--add-port="` number may vary :)